# В чем разница указать BufferedReader или указать буфер в методе read(byte[] byte)?

Tags: java

Вот есть такой пример

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:/data.txt");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:/result.txt");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
while (inputStream.available() > 0){

int count = inputStream.read(buffer); 
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count); 
}

inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
}
```

Вот тут несколько вопросов

1. Зачем нужно указывать `outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);`
   количество байтов для записи (от и до `0, count`) , если все равно
   метод `read(byte[] byte)` будет читать байты до тех пор пока буфер
   не заполнится или пока байты в файле не кончатся.

   Я так понимаю, что сколько дали байтов столько и записал
   `outputStream.write(buffer);`, зачем ставить от и до?
2. Зачем указывать буфер когда есть `BufferedInputStream()`? Если я
   правильно понимаю, то он будет работать также как если мы укажем  `byte[] byte = new byte[1000]`... Он так же будет буферизировать байты перед записью....

**ПРАВКА**

По поводу второго моего вопроса вот метод для примера

```
private void writeFile(File file, byte[] bytes) {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        bos.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (image != null) {
            image.close();
        }
        if (null != bos) {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ПРАВКА2**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если Вы хотите записать не весь `buffer`?

Comment: В `BufferedOutputStream` нет метода `write` с такой сигнатурой. Дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Методам `write(byte[] data)` или `write(byte[] data, int offset, int length)` классов `FileOutputStream` и `BufferedOutputStream` для записи массива все равно надо указать массив с прочитанными байтами, так что в любом случае перед записью байтов их надо будет прочитать во внутренний буфер. 
   Так что использование BufferedInputStream вместо FileInputStream не освобождает от необходимости читать данные во внутренний буфер.
   Более того, если не использовать специфические возможности буферизованных потоков, код для работы с буферизованными и небуферизованными потоками будет вообще одинаковый.
   Другое дело, что в большинстве случаев работа с буферизованными потоками будет на порядок быстрее.
2. Вы в своих рассуждениях забываете о том, что последний (а возможно, единственный) фрагмент входного файла не обязан по размеру совпадать с размером буфера, так что в любом случае при записи последнего фрагмента необходимо указывать, сколько байтов надо записать - а именно, столько, сколько фактически было прочитано. Иначе при записи к концу файла припишется лишний мусор, которого не было во входном файле (в случае единственного фрагмента это будут нули, а в случае неединственного повторно запишется часть предыдущего фрагмента).
   Поэтому в любом случае для записи по крайней мере одного (последнего) фрагмента надо будет использовать `write(byte[] data, int offset, int length)`,  а использование разных методов для записи последнего и непоследнего фрагментов - это лишнее усложнение кода.

Comment: У любого `InputStream` есть метод с сигнатурой `read(byte[])`, который читает кол-во байт, которое можно уместить в этот буфер, или меньше, если доступно меньше, и возвращает кол-во прочитанных символов, правьте

Comment: Да, конечно, позор на мою седую голову - не знаю, о чем думал. сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 2):

Создавая массив байт, вы вылеляете **1000** байт в куче, которые java любезно заливает вам нулями. Т.е. в этой строке: `byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];` вы говорите: пожалуйста, залей мне 1000 байт нулями и сохрани ссылку на массив в переменную buffer.

Когда вы вызываете метод `is.read(buffer)`, он читает то количество байт, которое **удалось прочитать**. И после возвращает количество байт, которые он прочитал, которое вы и сохраняете в переменную `count`.

После этих манипуляций у вас будет массив из **1000 байт,** `count` **из которых будут залиты прочитаными значениями, а остальные байты будут нулями**.

Чтобы не записывать в файл ненужные нули, которых по сути и не было в исходном файле, вы говорите: `os.write(buffer, 0, count)`, что равносильно: пожалуйста, залей мне в поток байты из буфера `buffer` начиная с `0`-го, всего `count` штук.

А в `BufferedOutputStream` нет метода `write` с сигнатурой `(byte[])`.

Еще раз. Так как выходной поток понятия не имеет, хотите вы записать в него весь массив байт, или часть, то он спрашивает у вас начальную позицию и количество байт, которые записывать.
Поймите. Это сделано для удобства. Вы можете считывать куда угодно байты из `InputStream`, создавать правильный массив нужной длины, копировать в него нужные значения и передавать на запись **целый массив**, не указывая начальную позицию и количество байт, но это:

1. Не рационально. Требуется процессорные время и дополнительный кусок памяти для создания массива нужной длины.
2. Не удобно, так как много лишнего кода.

Т.е. подведя черту: с таким api вы можете создать некоторый буфер размером **n** и переиспользовать его сколько угодно раз для чтения байт из потока, а переменная `count` будет сообщать, сколько **на данный момент** содержится **валидных** байт в вашем буфере. А так же: при чтении из потока в цикле учитывайте то, что может прочитаться меньшее кол-во байт, чем размер вашего буфера. И переменная `count` будет говорить о том, сколько было прочитано байт.

Как-то так

Comment: Второй вопрос насчет того, что можно написать вот так `new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStriam(fileName));` по сути `BufferedInputStream` будет создавать буфер и читать порциями, зачем тогда эти порции байтов считывать и опять перекладывать в буфер?

Comment: 1. Оперативная память. Если бы вы копировали файлы размером 1гб на вашей системе с 2гб оперативки с помощью `BufferedInputStream`, то я бы пожелал вам удачи. 2. На вкус и цвет...

Comment: Значит для предотвращения OOM?

Comment: Буферизированный поток просто дает вам возможность вернуться к тому, что было прочитано. При том это хранится в оперативе. Если не ошибаюсь, происходят еще какие-то оптимизации на чтение, но если вы читаете порциями, а не делаете вызоа `read` для одного байта, то не почувствуете. А чтобы записать эти байты в `OutputStream`,  вам все равно придется получить массив-буфер, и уже его записать. Т.е. по сути вы сравнили две разные вещи. Если помогло, то я добавлю в ответ более подробный материал.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы сказали 1. `дает вам возможность вернуться к тому, что было прочитано` - куда вернуться? 2. `При том это хранится в оперативе` - в смысле когда я добавляю `BufferedInputStream` - то он сохраняет в оперативу? А если я его не использую то не сохраняет? 3. `читаете порциями, а не делаете вызоа read для одного байта, то не почувствуете` - не понял сравнения... в каком случае не будет разницы? 4. `ам все равно придется получить массив-буфер` - зачем ? если я и тут могу пользоваться `BufferedOutputStream`.?

Comment: @Alexander, вы пишете: "Если бы вы копировали файлы размером 1гб на вашей системе с 2гб оперативки с помощью BufferedInputStream, то я бы пожелал вам удачи". Насколько я помню, по умолчанию у него буфер 8 kB, так что никаких проблем, связанных с размером файла, быть не должно.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, мне тоже непонятно, зачем автор так сделал. Это будет работать в разы медленнее, чем BufferedInputStream. Может, просто лень было считать смещения, которые требуются для BufferedInputStream.read, а скорость работы не важна?

Comment: @m.vokhm я добавил кусок кода в вопрос, зачем там считать какие то смещения? Взял себе файл взял байты и записал...

Comment: Я имел в виду смещения, которые нужны при чтении методу BufferedInputStream.read(byte[] data, int offset, int length). А класс BufferedOutputStream имеет метод write(byte b), который пишет один байт, и метод write(byte[] data, int offset, int length) который опять требует смещения, так что ваш код в дополнении ошибочный.

Comment: И вы забываете, что размер файла не обязан быть кратен размеру буфера. Если размер входного файла - 5 байт, что запишет ваш метод? 5 байт из файла + 995 байт нулей?

Comment: @m.vokhm код не может быть ошибочным так как он взят с рабочего примера и метод `write();` в классе `BufferedOutputStream` на самом деле имеет 3 конструктора `(int b)` - для одно байта , `(byte[],  int offset, int length) - для смещения и `(byte[] b)` - для записи массива байтов...

Comment: @m.vokhm и почему вы подумали, что я думаю, что размер файла должен быть кратным буферу? Мой вопрос до сих пор в том, что не совсем пойму, зачем явно указывать буфер если есть уже готовый класс который все это делает сам `BufferedOutputStream` . Нужно читать значит указал от куда читать и читаешь все что есть 5 байт или 100000 байт без разницы, нужно писать указал куда писать и передал `byte[]` и записал все что есть (как у меня в примере). Зачем нам нужен `byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];`

Comment: Вы явно не понимаете основ, а конкретно - выделение памяти. И где вы взяли ваш "рабочий" пример? Вы сами-то хоть его проверяли?  Вот справка, лично я там вижу всего 2 сигнатуры у метода `write`. Вы видите больше? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html

Comment: @Alexander добавил скриншот

Comment: @Alexander вот потому то и возник вопрос, потому что не совсем понимаю зачем выделять буфер если уже есть готовый класс обертка который все и так делает...

Comment: @Alexander,  "всего 2 сигнатуры у метода write" -- Там еще есть унаследованный write(byte[] b) (ниже, в списке унаследованных)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, вы пишете "нужно писать - указал куда писать и передал byte[] и записал все что есть" - а откуда этот byte[] с данными возьмется? Их же сначала прочитать надо, прежде чем писать?

Comment: @m.vokhm ну вот так бы сразу и сказали)) Теперь я разобрался в чем я запутался))